# Compiling haskell with llvm

Tags: macos, haskell, llvm, ghc

I'm starting to learn Haskell and I found out that `ghc` can compile using LLVM with the `-fllvm` flag. Whenever I use the flag, I get the error message:

```
<no location info>: error:
Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
         Make sure you have installed LLVM 3.7
ghc: could not execute: opt
```

However, I have `opt` in my `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.9.0/` folder. I'm on a Mac OS X and I've installed the full LLVM with `brew install llvm` but error persists. Is this a genuine version problem where I have to unistall LLVM and reinstall its 3.7 version? Or is `ghc` having trouble finding `opt` and there is some kind of search path I can modify to fix the problem? Thanks for the help and have a great day.

Comment: IIRC GHC is (or at least used to be) pretty touchy about the version of LLVM used, so you may need to install 3.7. The problem is that LLVM has a pretty frequent release cycle with breaking features. Keeping GHC working with these versions is a pain. See [this page](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ImprovedLLVMBackend) for more details.

Answer (score 8):

The [GHC documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/codegens.html#llvm-code-generator-fllvm) says that it's compatible with llvm-2.8+, but as you've discovered, it actually requires llvm-3.7.

The simplest way to get it is:

`brew install llvm@3.7`

This installs llvm binaries in your path with a `-3.7` suffix, like `clang-3.7`. GHC will need the unadorned names, which are in a subdirectory:

`export PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm@3.7/lib/llvm-3.7/bin:$PATH`